# url pattern matching php

Tags: php, html

I have a url of the format /?var1 = val1&var2 = val2;

I want to check for the presence of just var2 = val2 in the url using php. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $_GET superglobal

if(!empty($_GET['var2']) && $_GET['var2'] == 'val2')) // do something

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
if (isset($_GET['var2']))  // check if exist
{ 
  if ($_GET['var2'] == val2) // do something
}
```

Comment: Or, combined `if (isset($_GET['var2']) && $_GET['var2'] == val2)`. Due to [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

If this is not the `QUERY_STRING` for the request (in which case you should just use `$_GET` as @Spechal [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732297/url-pattern-matching-php/4732312#4732312)), you can use [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). It "*uses the same mechanism that PHP uses to populate the `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc. variables.*"

See also [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).